# How to check if session expired on ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, session, session-timeout

I am using asp.net and I have $.ajax calls in my web application for every request to the server.

I want to redirect the user to the Login page on session end.

In my web.config I set:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".CovertixAuthenticated" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" timeout="1"/>
</authentication>


  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1"/>
```

and I check in .ajaxError:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(xhr, props) {
    if (props.status == 401) {
        var ParentUrl = encodeURIComponent(window.parent.location.href);
        //alert(getLoginPage());
        document.location.href = getLoginPage() + "?ReturnUrl=" + ParentUrl;
    }
});
```

The problem is I get responseCode = 500 (Internal server error)

What is the best way to check if session expired on ajax call, or how can I redirect the user to the login page automatically when session ends?

Comment: 500 means a real error on your server which was not handled.

Comment: The way you plan to do it seems the good one, you only have to identify what the problem is exactly on the server. A common problem is not having Sessions enabled in your handler and could result in a 500 error. Trying enabling debug mode, or check step by step with the debugger...

Comment: Bear in mind that ajax calls will keep the session alive, so if you have periodic polling of some type then the session probably won't timeout.

Comment: @Bartdude
Thanks all for the answers! I checked again, and you are right, I have a real error on server, I enter my web method and I try to read a value from the session, but it expired.... How can I change the status code and throw an error from the web method? (c#)

Comment: Well now that would be up to you to try some code. The status code you find in HttpResponse object (I'm still using framework 2.0 myself so I won't put code), and from where I see it the error handling should be done by Javascript, as your code here above does actually.

Comment: @Bartdude I want to use the code I have above, but if I throw an exception I still get 500... What I wanted to ask is if I can change it from my code behind... I tried throwing a new httpexception with error code 401, or set Response.StatusCode = 401, but I still get 500 in the ajax error handler (props).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the help!

I just forgot to add to my web.config:

```
  <location path="MyPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Now I get 401 as expected!